# what printing against only 'c1'?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c1='A';
    char *p1;

    p1=&c1;

    printf("%p %p %p %p", p1, &p1, c1, &c1);

    return 0;
}

output:

0x7ffd26ad7087 0x7ffd26ad7088 0x41 0x7ffd26ad7087
```

Here, 'p1', '&c1' denoting address of 'c1'.

'&p1' denoting address of pointer  '*p1'.

'c1' printing '0x41', what it is?

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
char c1='A';
```

`c1` as character variable holding char constant `'A'`. To print char variable you should be using `%c` instead of `%p`. To print address of char variable use `%p` and `p` conversion specifier requires an argument of type `void *`. For e.g

```
printf("%p %p %c %p", p1, (void*)&p1, c1, (void*)&c1);
```

*'c1' denoting what?* Its a *character  variable* and it can hold a valid character i. that is `'A'`.

Comment: 'c1' printing '0x41', what it is?

Comment: To print `c1` which a `char` you have used `%p` there, that prints the address.

Comment: I am not asking how to print. here I print 4 things. 3 of them understood but I didn't understand what c1 printing or what it is '0x41'? it's a garbage value? 
and I know '%p' prints address, '%c' prints character.